# JS - Defining prototype methods

Tags: javascript

Is there a difference between this syntax

```
function Foo() {}

Foo.prototype.method1 = function() {};
Foo.prototype.method2 = function() {};
```

and this one?

```
function Foo() {}

Foo.prototype = {
    method1: function() {},
    method2: function() {}
}
```

Should one be prefered to the other?

Comment: First is adding, second is replacing to `Foo.prototype`

Comment: If you want to use object literal syntax, just use `Object.assign`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slight difference between those two options. I would recommend using the former to preserve the `constructor` property pointing to the actual constructor function used to create the object. In the following example you'll see the difference under the hood of both options:

- Foo used the `prototype.newMethod` syntax.
- Bar used the `prototype = {...}` syntax.

[image: Difference between extending the prototype and assigning an object to it]

In case you'd like to use the Bar syntax, you can always set the `constructor` property to the correct function.

I hope this helps, let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't the empty Foo function the constructor?

Comment: Yeah, but if you check the Bar example there's no constructor because the prototype was overridden by the object literal assignment. I think it is cleaner to use the `Foo` approach so you don't mess with the prototype chain.